# Docker containers on AWS ECS always shows STOPPED

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I am setting up a new AWS ECS cluster with CodePiepline. I am following below documentations:
[AWS ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html) and  [blog](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-ECS-CLI-Docker-Compose-Wordpress-EC2-Type.php).

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3.0"
services:

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.4
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
        - MYSQL_USER=db
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
      ports:
        - "8003:3306"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

I followed steps mentioned in Blog tutorial and when I am doing below step, I get output exactly as mentioned in blog post

```
$ ecs-cli compose up --cluster xyz --cluster-config xyz --force-update
INFO[0000] Using ECS task definition                     TaskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0000] Starting container...                         container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/webserver
INFO[0000] Starting container...                         container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/php-fpm
INFO[0000] Starting container...                         container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/mariadb
INFO[0000] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/mariadb desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0000] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/webserver desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0000] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/php-fpm desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0012] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/mariadb desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0012] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/webserver desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0012] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/php-fpm desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0024] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/mariadb desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0024] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/webserver desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0024] Describe ECS container status                 container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/php-fpm desiredStatus=RUNNING lastStatus=PENDING taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0036] Stopped container...                          container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/mariadb desiredStatus=STOPPED lastStatus=STOPPED taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0036] Stopped container...                          container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/webserver desiredStatus=STOPPED lastStatus=STOPPED taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
INFO[0036] Stopped container...                          container=ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/php-fpm desiredStatus=STOPPED lastStatus=STOPPED taskDefinition="xyz-core:1"
```

But when I try to see the images/containers available or running in my cluster, it gives me below error messages:

```
$ ecs-cli ps --cluster xyz
Name                                            State                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Ports                       TaskDefinition  Health
ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/mariadb    STOPPED ExitCode: 137                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            host:8003->3306/tcp  xyz-core:1   UNKNOWN
ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/webserver  STOPPED Reason: CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/manu/project/xyz-core/php                              xyz-core:1   UNKNOWN
ea894de8-0c31-4879-90ee-e39909f423a5/php-fpm    STOPPED ExitCode: 137                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        xyz-core:1   UNKNOWN
efd12ec9-af27-4f2b-abe2-39e9e3a25a68/webserver  STOPPED Reason: CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/manu/project/xyz-core/php                              xyz-core:1   UNKNOWN
efd12ec9-af27-4f2b-abe2-39e9e3a25a68/php-fpm    STOPPED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      xyz-core:1   UNKNOWN
efd12ec9-af27-4f2b-abe2-39e9e3a25a68/mariadb    STOPPED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      xyz-core:1   UNKNOWN
```

I tried to do some search, but can't find any solution to this problem. I am new to docker-compose and AWS ECS.

Please let me know if any other details are needed to investigate the issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you try and mount the volumes read-only? I would avoid mounting the same folder (. in your case) to more than 1 container.

Comment: How should I do it? I am using docker first time in deployment.

Comment: You can do: - .:/application:ro But ideally you should map to /application only the relevant information for each container: ./mariadb:/application for mariadb, ./nginx:/application for nginx and so on. You can first try the read only solution and see if that helps

Comment: I tried two solution. you can see the `docker-compose.yaml` version and output [here](https://gist.github.com/manu-sparheld/c6754234e32d4c5b460a784b4f74123b)

Comment: what I don't understand is why there are different EXIT codes all the time... Is there enough memory on the box where you try to run this? Can you also do my suggestion to split the way to map the volumes?

Comment: 1. By default it's using t2.micro, but I guess I can change to some bigger one's. 2. I tried to mount individual containers but getting same errors.

Comment: t2.micro has only 1Gb memory. I doubt you can run a mariadb server on that. Not to mention the php app. Can you try on a bigger instance? I would say at least t2.medium

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191086/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-mihai).

Comment: Can we connect again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you should remove the volumes from the docker-compose.yml file.

It should looks something like this:

```
version: "3.0"
services:

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.4
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=food
        - MYSQL_USER=food
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
      ports:
        - "8003:3306"

    webserver:
      build: ./nginx
      image: food-service-webserver:1.0
      ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"

    php-fpm:
      build: ./php-fpm
      image: food-service-app:1.0
```

For the webserver and php-fpm services there should be separate Dockerfile's that build the images.

**Note:** Make sure you enable the force deployment option in ECS cluster.

Good luck!